# RegEx for splitting a list of words with multiple capturing groups

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the following string:

```
one two three four five six seven eight nine
```

And I am trying to construct a regular expression that groups the string into three groupings:

1. Group 1: 'one two three'
2. Group 2: 'four five six'
3. Group 3: 'seven eight nine'

I have tried variations of `(.*\b(one|two|three)?)(.*\b(four|five|six)?)(.*\b(seven|eight|nine)?)` but this pattern splits the full match into one group that contains the full string - [the demo can be found here](https://regex101.com/r/lBkbyy/1).

Trying `(.*\b(one|two|three))(.*\b(four|five|six))(.*\b(seven|eight|nine))` seems to get me closer to what I want but the match information panel shows that the pattern identifies two matches each containing six capture groups.

I am using the OR statement because the groups can be of any length, e.g. `two three four`, applying the pattern to this string should identify two groups -

1. Group 1: 'two'
2. Group 2: 'three four'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A large regex that probably does it

```
(?=.*\b(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)\b)(\b(?:one|two|three)(?:\s+(?:one|two|three))*\b)?.+?(\b(?:four|five|six)(?:\s+(?:four|five|six))*\b)?.+?(\b(?:seven|eight|nine)(?:\s+(?:seven|eight|nine))*\b)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/rUtkyU/1

Readable version

```
 (?=
      .* \b 
      (?:
           one
        |  two
        |  three
        |  four
        |  five
        |  six
        |  seven
        |  eight
        |  nine
      )
      \b 
 )
 (                             # (1 start)
      \b   
      (?: one | two | three )

      (?:
           \s+ 
           (?: one | two | three )
      )*
      \b 
 )?                            # (1 end)

 .+? 
 (                             # (2 start)
      \b        
      (?: four | five | six )

      (?:
           \s+ 
           (?: four | five | six )
      )*
      \b     
 )?                            # (2 end)

 .+?   
 (                             # (3 start)
      \b          
      (?: seven | eight | nine )

      (?:
           \s+ 
           (?: seven | eight | nine )
      )*
      \b   
 )?                            # (3 end)
```

Comment: Yes it does, thank you very much @sln! It's a behemoth of an expression though, I wonder what your thought process was when you pieced it together? I really struggle with that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what your desired output might be. However, this expression passes and creates several separate capturing groups to be simple to call:

```
((one|two|three)\s.*?)((four|five|six)\s.*?)((seven|eight|nine)\s.*)
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Aqyrbl/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

This snippet shows that what various capturing groups might return:

```js
const regex = /((one|two|three)\s.*?)((four|five|six)\s.*?)((seven|eight|nine)\s.*)/gm;
const str = `one two three four five six seven eight nine

two three four six seven eight`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Emma. I needed the match to contain just three groupings, where group 1 spans 'one two three', group 2 spans `four five six` and group 3 spans `seven eight nine`, I'm sorry if I haven't been clearer in the post. The visualiser is helpful, thank you for suggesting it.

Comment: Note that this question is about R, _not_ JavaScript.  Every language has a different regex API, so an answer in one language may not necessarily help with another language.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you want to find groups of three number words at a time:

```
x <- c("one two three four five six seven eight nine")
regexp <- gregexpr("\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){2}", x)
regmatches(x, regexp)[[1]]

[1] "one two three"    "four five six"    "seven eight nine"
```

If you want a more general solution, which doesn't require knowing a priori what the length of the input is (i.e. how many groups of three are present), then you might have to use an iterative approach:

```
parts <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
output <- character(0)
for (i in seq(from=1, to=length(parts), by=3)) {
    output <- c(output, paste(parts[i], parts[i+1], parts[i+2]))
}
output

[1] "one two three"    "four five six"    "seven eight nine"
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Tim. Unfortunately the groups can be of any length but a strict subset of the original string, e.g. two `three four six seven eight` or `two three four` so I think the words would need to be explicitly specified in the pattern. I've tried doing this in the demo linked in my post but can't get the matches to span multiple words in each group.

Comment: Then you need to rephrase your question.

Comment: Sorry, I had tried including the second example at the end of the post to convey that but the wording is clumsy.